# How can I get entry id in field

Tags: plugin-development, field, fieldtypes, custom-fieldtype, custom-field

I create a new filed type and attached it to entries. Now I need to get the entry id which the field is attached to.

I tried `$this->element` in my field class, but got an error said that I'm calling an unknown property.

Any way to do that please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Way one:***
Inside the field class, there is a `inputTemplateVariables` function with two params, like this

```
protected function inputTemplateVariables($value = null, ElementInterface $element = null): array
{
     $vars = parent::inputTemplateVariables($value, $element);

     $settings = $this->getSettings();

     //here you can get element
     $entryId = $element->id;

     return $vars;
}
```

***Way two:***
In your plugin's main file, put codes below into `init()` function

```
Craft::$app->getView()->hook('cp.entries.edit.details', function (&$context) 
{

     //here you can also get the element id
     //you can save it into session and use it anywhere you need
     $id = $context['entry']['id'];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It may depend on where in the request you need to access the element.

If you need to access the element in a Field class on your Entry Edit page, the `getInputHtml` method may be useful:

```
public function getInputHtml($value, ElementInterface $element = null): string
{
    // $element stuff

    return Craft::$app->getView()->renderTemplate('my-plugin/field',
    [
        'field' => $this,

        // make the Element available in your field's input template
        'element' => $element
    ]);
}
```

If you need to access the element in a Field class after the Element is saved there is the [afterSaveElement](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-base-field.html#method-afterelementsave) method:

```
public function afterElementSave(ElementInterface $element, bool $isNew)
{
    parent::afterElementSave($element, $isNew);

    // $element stuff
}
```

Note: The Entry ID may not exist while a new entry is being created. Accessing the Element via the `afterElementSave` ensures that the Entry has been saved and has an ID.

Comment: Thanks! But I hope I can get the entry id after I open the entry editing page in CP. So this function is not for me.

Comment: @yuxia then the getInputHtml https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-base-field.html#method-getinputhtml might be something for you.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the `getInputHtml` method Robin mentions as well.

Comment: @BenParizek Thanks for your code. But I don't understand what the `getInputHtml` do.  Maybe I didn't make myself clear.  Basically there are two Asset field types: A and B. Let's say a user selected three images to A, Ctrl+s to save and then he can only select these three images to B. The field B is what I want to create.

 `afterElementSave` has the limit which is users have to save to trigger this function.

Comment: @BenParizek You are absolutely right! I can get element via `getInputHtml`. But I have to rewrite the template in this function which is gonna take too much effort